# Add a link on StackOverflow to Joel's GoogleTalk about StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I just watched Joel's interesting talk at Google called ["Learning from StackOverflow.com"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ&feature=PlayList&p=05D94CA1ADAF07B5&index=2) and was wondering if we should add a link to this talk at the bottom of the StackOverflow page.

Or maybe put it in the FAQ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=site:blog.stackoverflow.com+joel+google+talk http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/joel-talks-about-stack-overflow-at-google/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe in the About page, but other than that, you don't need to spam up the pages with more links than are necessary. Joel talking somewhere about SO isn't what I would consider anywhere close to a "required" link on the pages.

Answer (score 2):

[It was mentioned on, and linked to from the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/joel-talks-about-stack-overflow-at-google/) - that's probably enough.

Comment: @Shog9, except that is now buried back in the mists of time of Jeff's blog. I like the idea of sticking a link on the about page. What about it Jeff?

Comment: I think it was a decent talk, but most of what's actually useful for SO users has been covered at one point or another in the blog - so if anyone really wants to understand SO, they'll read all that... and encounter the talk as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19063/19068#19068), it's on the blog and that's good enough. In fact, I would go further and say that is precisely one of the reasons the blog exists. StackOverflow is not about the talks that Joel and Jeff give. Additionally, Joel's talk is not the only one that exists, Jeff spent 10 - 15 minutes talking about the development of SO in the middle of [Phil Haack's PDC 2008 talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC21/) and I wouldn't be surprised if there's more in the future, you won't be able to link them all. If a user is curious about SO, its development and business issues, they should look at the blog and go through previous posts. But links on the bottom of a SO page should be relevant to a generic SO user, I do not believe talks that Jeff and Joel give fall into this category.

Comment: @yshuditelu, actually you're right. If we start just adding links for all potential SO talks we'll get in a mess. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh, the site isn't really about promoting Jeff or Joel. It isn't even really about showing people good talks. It is only peripherially about providing resources. It is about asking questions and getting answers. Jeff and Joel both have excellent blogs for this sort of thing.

Comment: @EBGreen, guess you haven't seen the talk. It doesn't really do that at all.

Comment: Doesn't really do what?

Comment: The talk doesn't just "promote Jeff or Joel". The talk is about the basis of the determination of an identified need for a site like SO and the reasoning of why certain features were included, or excluded.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the talk promoted Jeff or Joel, simply that posting a link to their talks would.

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you meant now.